# Liquibase(Postgres): Add uniqiue constraint with ignore case

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I would like to add a unique constraint on a column of type varchar using liquibase on a postgres table, but could not find an option. It does not allow me to use UPPER or LOWER for a column name.
e.g.

```
<addUniqueConstraint columnNames="column_a, column_b, upper(column_c)"
                             deferrable="true" initiallyDeferred="true" disabled="false"
                             constraintName="constraint_uk" tableName="table_a"/>
```

Comment: what exception are you getting and which vesion of liquibase and postgre are you using?

Comment: bilak's question is a good one, another alternative is just write the changeset in regular sql: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html

Comment: Postgres is not resolving upper as a function. It thinks upper(column_c) is a column. Hence it throws an PSQLException Error: column "upper(NAME) named in the key does not exist.

I am not specifying the any liquibase version in my gradle, so the compatible version for springboot 2.1.7.RELEASE is pulled. I believe its 3.6.3

Also, my postgres version is 12.3.

@ronak: I will check the url and give it a try. Thanks!